# How to run hive script from hive cli

Tags: hadoop, hive, hivecli

I have hive script custsales.hql now I want to run it from hive cli as

```
hive (pract5)> run /user/training/hdfs_location/custsales.hql
```

but it does not execute.  Please guide.  I know we can run it from command line with

```
$ hive -f /home/training/local_location/custsales.hql
```

but this is not my requirement.

Comment: `source path/to/script' but it works for local fs AFAIK

Comment: Thank you very much leftjoin it is working with source command.What is AFAIK.

Comment: user8167344, AFAIK -  as far as I know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `source path/to/script` command.