# How can we pass multiple hql files to hive/beeline?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to run file_1.hql and file_2.hql in one hive session. How can I do that?
I was thinking of passing both files as hive -f file_1.hql file_2.hql.
But -f only takes one file. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use `source` hive command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46847977/2700344 You can include many `source` commands in your script

Answer (score 3):

What about using bash:

```
hive -e "$(cat file1.hql file2.hql)"
```

Comment: Updated solution works, but cat showdata1.sql showdata.sql | hive -f - never worked

Comment: glad your tests succeed; do not hesitate to star